# Count of selected rows is not updated correctly in a DT datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple shiny app

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2")

             ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3")

             )
           )))
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2","Rows selected",
                 value = input$hot3_rows_selected,
                 min=0
    )
  })



  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(
      iris %>% rowid_to_column("Row") %>% mutate(Row = ""),
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = "Select",
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(className = "select-checkbox", targets = 0, orderable = FALSE)),
        select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:first-child")
      ))
}
```

I have a `numericInput()` which should normally display the count of rows selected in the datatable but as you will see it displays only the first row selected and not the count of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the count of rows selected you need the length of `input$hot3_rows_selected` (use `length(input$hot3_rows_selected)` instead).

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(
    "Application",
    tabPanel("General",
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(uiOutput("tex2")),
            mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("hot3"))
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

    library(tidyverse)
    output$tex2 <- renderUI({
        numericInput("text2", "Rows selected",
                     value = length(input$hot3_rows_selected),
                     min = 0)
    })

    output$hot3 <- DT::renderDataTable(
        iris %>% 
            rowid_to_column("Row") %>% 
            mutate(Row = ""),
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = "Select",
        options = list(
            columnDefs = list(list(className = "select-checkbox", targets = 0, orderable = FALSE)),
            select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:first-child")
        )
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]